# Passing selected option in URl to Jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a way that i can link to a page containing a jquery ui tab set and pass the selected variable in the url link to automatically show a particular tab depending in which link was clicked to reach the page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by constructing the url like so http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#tabs-2

Essentially you are passing the id of the tab's content div after the hash. It worked on Chrome, but it should probably work everywhere.